# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-cursor

I'm creating an app that list all images in my phone and I'm using media content provider to do it.
 my problem is I always get this error in my app wherever i run it.

```
08-28 00:31:27.001 16706-16706/com.chill.leoj.burp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.chill.leoj.burp, PID: 16706
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chill.leoj.burp/com.chill.leoj.burp.Photos}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference
                                                                     at com.chill.leoj.burp.Photos.onCreate(Photos.java:159)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2601) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Photos.java:159

```
  if (thumbCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                newVVI.thumbPath = thumbCursor.getString(thumbCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
                Log.v("", newVVI.thumbPath);
            }
```

pls can you help me to solve this. Thank you in advance!

this is my code:

```
  Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Uri uri1 = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getContentUri("external");

    String[] thumbColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID };

    String[] mediaColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE };


Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,
        mediaColumns, null, null, null);



    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            ImageViewInfo newVVI = new ImageViewInfo();
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
            Cursor thumbCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri1, thumbColumns, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID
                    + "=" + id, null, null);
            if (thumbCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                newVVI.thumbPath = thumbCursor.getString(thumbCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
                Log.v("", newVVI.thumbPath);
            }

            newVVI.filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            newVVI.title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE));
            Log.v("", newVVI.title);
            newVVI.mimeType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE));
            Log.v("", newVVI.mimeType);
            ImageRows.add(newVVI);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());


        cursor.close();
        ImageAdapter = new ImageGalleryAdapter(Photos.this, ImageRows);

    }
    listView.setAdapter(new ImageGalleryAdapter(this, ImageRows));
```

Edit:
I forgot to tell I also try what is written on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) and debug it by myself but nothing really happens and i dont know if I'm doing it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`if (thumbCursor.moveToFirst()!=null && (thumbCursor.moveToFirst())`

in

```
if (thumbCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                newVVI.thumbPath = thumbCursor.getString(thumbCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
                Log.v("", newVVI.thumbPath);
            }
```

and

`if (Cursor.moveToFirst()!=null && (Cursor.moveToFirst())`

in

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            ImageViewInfo newVVI = new ImageViewInfo();
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
            Cursor thumbCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri1, thumbColumns, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID
                    + "=" + id, null, null);
            if (thumbCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                newVVI.thumbPath = thumbCursor.getString(thumbCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
                Log.v("", newVVI.thumbPath);
            }
```

Comment: thank you very much this is the answer I've been looking for! :)